# Terraform ternary operation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have terraform for provisioning GCP VM and it can be provision both OS (windows & Unix).

I have variable **os_distro=windows**.

I need **windows-startup-script-ps1 = "${file("disk.ps1")}"** inside metadata ONLY if **os_distro** is **windows**.

```
  meta_data_default = {
    google-monitoring-enable = 1
    google-logging-enable    = 1
    windows-startup-script-ps1 = var.os_distro == "windows" ? "${file("disk.ps1")}" : ""
  }
```

The above block works if **os_distro==windows**, but not require `windows-startup-script-ps1` when **os_distro==unix**

Please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Try replacing the `""` empty string with `null`.

Comment: Thanks Mark. it works. 

But My requirement is if it is UNIX, I don't want **windows-startup-script-ps1** variable, becuase this variable only for Windows running powershell in startup.

Any idea ?

Comment: Does setting it to `null` not remove it?

Comment: It doesn't mean to have ```null``` for other than windows.  means, this variable should be defined only for windows, If other, Not required to defined variable.

Comment: See what the Terraform docs say about `null` [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html). It is considered the absence of a setting. It means the value is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that your interpolation syntax is deprecated. `"${file("disk.ps1")}"` should instead be `file("disk.ps1")`.

Now for the main topic. Could you clarify, where is this `meta_data_default` block being defined? As others have noted in the comments, using `null` instead of `""` after the ternary operator *should* work. But, if for some reason it doesn't, then you can do two things.

If `meta_data_default` is an input parameter, you can put a ternary around the entire object:

```
meta_data_default = var.os_distro == "windows" ? {
    google-monitoring-enable = 1
    google-logging-enable    = 1
    windows-startup-script-ps1 = file("disk.ps1")
  } : {
    google-monitoring-enable = 1
    google-logging-enable    = 1
  }
```

Or, if you want to keep it DRY (do not repeat yourself):

```
meta_data_default = merge(
  {
    google-monitoring-enable = 1
    google-logging-enable    = 1
  }, 
  var.os_distro == "windows" ? 
    {
      windows-startup-script-ps1 = file("disk.ps1")
    } : 
    {}
)
```

If `meta_data_default` is a block within a resource, you can use the `dynamic` statement:

```
resource "some_google_resource" "myresource" {
  ...

  dynamic "meta_data_default" {
    count = var.os_distro == "windows" ? 1 : 0
    content {
      google-monitoring-enable = 1
      google-logging-enable    = 1
      windows-startup-script-ps1 = file("disk.ps1")
    }
  }

  dynamic "meta_data_default" {
    count = var.os_distro == "windows" ? 0 : 1
    content {
      google-monitoring-enable = 1
      google-logging-enable    = 1
    }
  }
}
```

This will create the first style of `meta_data_default` block (with the `windows-startup-script-ps1` field) if it's on Windows, or the second style (without that field) if it's on Unix.

As an aside, here's a trick I often use for automatically determining if Terraform is running on Windows or Unix:

```
locals {
  is_windows = dirname("/") == "\\"
}
```

If the OS uses a backslash as a path separator, it's windows, otherwise it's unix-based. This may or may not be useful for you, as I'm not sure if your `os_distro` variable is supposed to represent the OS that Terraform is running on, or the OS of a remote machine that you're creating/updating.